# How to scroll android webview when softkey's up

Tags: android, webview

Nothing else to say additionally to this article's title. What I need to know is how to scroll an android webview to the top when I touch an input and the softkey appears.

Note: This webview must scroll the same amount of pixels that the softkey has of height.

Answer (score 1):

THere's only three options you can take when the softkeyboard comes up.  YOu can do nothing, you can resize (your app is relaid out to take the space above the keyboard), or you can pan (your app is shifted by enough to ensure the active field is on screen).  There is no option to scroll more than that.  There is no way to detect a keyboard has been launched reliably.

To turn on pan mode, in your manifest add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`

Comment: I will try it out. If it's the solution to my problem, I'll tell you. Thanks.